# How can I create a new graph using output of an API (or the elements of another graph)?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have a graph that I create an MST from using the Kruskal API. I'd like to visualise that MST but I don't see any immediately obvious way of doing so.

```
let originalGraph = cytoscape({
  ...
  elements: jsonData
});

let mst = originalGraph.elements().kruskal(e => e.data().weight);

let newGraph = cytoscape({
  ...
  elements: ???
});
```

How can I extract the elements from the MST (or indeed any other graph like `originalGraph`) such that I can pass it into a new cytoscape instance to visualise? Currently my workaround is:

```
let newGraph = cytoscape({
  ...
  elements: mst.map(e => { return { position: e.position(), data: e.data() } })
});
```

But I can't help but feel like I'm missing a much easier way. On a potentially related note, I saw that the docs say that `.data()` will refer to just the first element of a collection, but is there a way to get a reference to the data the same way it was passed in (like `jsonData` above) without resorting to `.map(...)`?

My apologies if the answer is obvious; I've only just started using Cytoscape.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the documentation in more detail again and I figured it out. The format for `jsonData` is literally called the "plain JSON representation" in the docs and can be gotten with the [`.jsons()`](https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.jsons) function, and passed to a new graph.